# ClassNotFoundException em Testes com mockito em Java

Tags: java, mockito

Olá,

Ao testar uma classe usando o Mockito, me deparei com o erro “ClassNotFoundException”. Infelizmente não consigo resolver este erro.
Todas as minhas dependências estão instaladas, mas o erro persiste.
Já verifiquei inúmeros tópicos aqui mesmo no StackOverflow, mas todas as soluções não conseguiram resolver meu problema, mesmo eu recriando a estrutura de pastas do projeto

Segundo minhas pesquisas, o problema seria como as pastas seriam organizadas (src/projeto...), mas desde o inicio de meu projeto sempre segui os padrões de boas práticas em meus códigos.

A respeito da instalação dos paths JARs, todos foram instalados manualmente, e suas versões estão especificadas nas imagens abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

As suas classes de teste do JUnit devem ficar em um diretório paralelo. Por exemplo, se seu código está em

```
projeto/src/main/java/br/com/pizzaria/...
```

Seus fontes de teste devem ficar em, por convenção:

```
projeto/src/test/java/br/com/pizzaria/...
```